# Apache Transaction: create directory

Tags: java, io, transactions

I need to use Apache transaction to create a library that provide io common functionality with transactional behavior . in the [docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-transaction/apidocs/org/apache/commons/transaction/file/FileResourceManager.html) , Apache say that resource must not contain "/".

how to let the resource be mapped to directory not file.
currently to create a directory i am adding "\x" to the end of resource id and then create resource this will create a directory containing empty file x , then i delete resource x.

is there a better a way? and is there already implemented io common functionality with transactional behavior.